# Would these be idiomatic to ask how responsible someone is: "How much of the blame is on him?" OR "How much of it is because of him?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC [Tomato shortage](https://www.bbc.com/news/64762429)

**"Tomato shortage: How far is Brexit to blame?"**

At first I could not quite decide what exactly the question is focusing on. I thought people have not yet understood that the problem was actually caused by Brexit, so it still seems a little bit **far away** for people to come to understand it.

However, as I read, I understood that the text was trying to reveal **how much of the problem (tomato shortage) is caused by the Brexit.*

Then I start to think about the question and I tried to adapt it to find out the share of someone in any problem in daily life. As a non-native speaker, if I was to form a question to find out "how much is someone - amongst others- can be held responsible for a problem, I would not be able to form the sentence by using **"how far"**.

I would probably form the sentence like one of these;

**"How much of the blame is on him?**" or

**"To what extent can he be blamed?"** or

**"How much of it is because of him?"** or

But since I am a non-native speaker, I can not decide whether or not these would be as idiomatic as **"How far is he to blame?"**

Would they be? Or Is **"How far is he to blame?"** the only way to ask about it in an idiomatic way?

Comment: Hi. These are all perfectly acceptable and idiomatic in the UK at least. I think you have understood it well. How far is Brexit to blame? means the same as How much/to what extent is Brexit to blame?  However "how far" and "to what extent" are a little more formal than the "how much" example.

Comment: I agree with @BillyKerr although there are subtleties: some of those are generally informal ("he fouled up") while others are more formal ("he's being sued for fouling up").

Answer (score 4):

"How far is he to blame" actually sounds weird to this American, though it's a [valid if dated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far%20to%20blame&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) form that still sees some use.

Some of your rephrasings flow a little better in casual speech than others, but all of them are fine. I'd add **"How much is he to blame?"** and **"How much can he be blamed?"** into the mix: in short, it's not a fixed idiom and can be varied in all the ways you've tried and more.

A subtlety of meaning, however: most of these ask how much he ***should*** be blamed, while "How much of the blame is on him?" can be used the same way but more literally asks how much he ***has*** been blamed by others, regardless of whether he's at fault.

Comment: 'How far is _something or someone_ to blame' is quite normal in the UK but rather 'educated' or 'academic'.